# SQL - auto populate column with correct values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the SQL table where `CODE1` and `CODE2` are populated and for `CODE3` I have input the values that I would like to auto populate. There are over 500.000 rows in total.

```
CODE1   CODE2   CODE3  
 1      100       A  
 2      100       A  
 3      200       B  
 4      300       A  
 5      300       A  
 1      300       A  
 5      400       A  
 6      400       A  
 2      400       A  
 7      500       C
 8      300       A
 7      600       C
 2      800       A
 3      900       B
```

I have to auto populate  `CODE3` in order to group all connections defined by CODE1 & CODE2. 
If `CODE 2` has the same value (100 for rows:1,2) `CODE 3` will have same value (A) and if `CODE 1`  has the same value (1 for rows:1,6) `CODE 3` will have same value (A).

Any idea how to achieve this?

Much appreciated!

Comment: How is CODE3 has A for 4th row?

Comment: @Madhivanan-  Because of row 6 where CODE1 = 1 and CODE 1 already has value A and all that relation (rows: 4,5,6) will have same CODE3, make sense?

Comment: @Ashish Kumar - Because of the row 2 where CODE1=2 and CODE 3 =A Rows 7, 8,9 are part of the same group CODE 2 = 400 & row9 CODE1=2 which for row2 already received value A.

Comment: A => ? B => ? I think you need to define it this way. Question is very ambiguous as it is.

Comment: What I am getting is that Code1 has value 1 at that time Code3 has A and Code1 has value 2 at that time Code3 has B now when you have 300 as Code 2 so u r checking the all code1 associated with 300 which are 4,5,1 and 1 has already code3 as A so you used A for all. Same as for code2 as 400 it has code1 as 5,6,2 in which you have code3 value for 2 as A so you again used A for all 3. Am I right?

Comment: @SNC - row1 - CODE3=A as first value / row2 - because of CODE2 =100 which is the same as row1 results in CODE3=A same as row1 / row3 - no other connections with other rows CODE1=3 no more value 3 in CODE1 column and CODE2=200 no more value 200 in CODE2 column / row4 - is A because is part of the group (rows 4,5,5) defined by CODE2 value (300) and part of this group is row 6 where CODE1=1 and this was already had assign A on row1.

Comment: does this depend on the order the rows display at all? How are you sorting? It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Daniel E.- I am trying to assign a value in CODE3 column in order to identify groups (Ex: Group A = rows:1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,13). A group is where CODE1 value is identical (ex: row1 and row6) or CODE2 value is the same (ex: row1 and row2).

Comment: Then what happens if code1 matches 1 value and code 2 matches a different value? `1,300` matches `1,100` or `4,300`? what sets the initial code? Why is `4,300` `A` already?

Comment: @Daniel E. - if code1 matches 1 value and code 2 matches a different value they will receive the same code3 and all the other rows that match code1 value or code2 value will receive the same code 3. 4,300, is A because row6 1,300 has code3 =A and this will determine all other rows where code2=300 to have value A

Comment: How did you decide 1,100 should be A?

Comment: @ Daniel E.- that is my 1st row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understood it:

```
WITH CODE_COUNTS AS (
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE2) as CODE2_DUPES
FROM CODES
) 
SELECT 
  CODE1, 
  CODE2,
  CASE WHEN CD.CODE2_DUPES > 1 THEN 'A'
      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CODE_COUNTS
                   WHERE CD.CODE1 = CODE1 AND CODE2_DUPES > 1) THEN 'A'
      ELSE 'B' 
  END CODE3
FROM CODE_COUNTS CD;
```

This code first counts duplicates within each CODE2 in CTE. After that for each CODE1 we checks whether any other row with same CODE1 has a CODE2 with number of duplicates greater than one.

[SqlFiddle that provides requested results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/15409/3)

**Update**

```
WITH CODE_COUNTS AS (
SELECT code1, code2, 
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE2) as CODE2_DUPES,
   CASE -- Assign row number within CODE1, where CODE2 is unique
     WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE2) > 1 THEN 0
     ELSE  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE1 ORDER BY CODE2) 
   END rn
FROM CODES
) 
SELECT CD.CODE1, CD.CODE2,
 CASE WHEN CD.CODE2_DUPES > 1 THEN 'A' -- CODE is not unique
 ELSE CHAR(ASCII('A') + SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (
           ORDER BY CODE1) ) END CODE3
FROM CODE_COUNTS CD
ORDER BY CD.CODE1, CD.CODE2
```

There is a bit of magic involved in the code above, I will try to explain:

1. I assumed that where `CODE2` group has several records, we assign `A`.
2. Where `CODE2` has several records we assign Zero to `rn` field, which means that `A` will be incremented by Zero for all associated records.
3. Where `CODE2` is unique, we do running count of `CODE1` and increment `CODE3` accordingly.

[Sql Fiddle for the updated example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d110/11)

I have kept the original version of SQL as it a simpler version of the same algorithm essentially.

Comment: There are over 500.000 records and there are not only A, B values for CODE3, I don`t think this is working, it has to take row by row and check is it already has a value if not assign next available one.

Comment: Please update your question then, code above gives same result as in your example.

Comment: Number of records are not relevant to the question btw.

Comment: Thank you Bulat, I will try this and post back soon. Much appreciated!